# "Package operation failed" when trying to install Canon printer driver

Tags: package-management, printing, canon

I'm totally a beginner, so I hope someone can answer this question in plain English.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I have a Canon lpb 2900. I downloaded the driver as in the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190), extracted the deb
and ran it with Ubuntu Software Center. Then I got this:

[image: Screenshot of error]

I tried something from the old questions of this site but they didn't work.

Comment: did you tried installing .tar.gz package?

Comment: looks like processor issue.Please check the version of the package if it is compatible with your processor

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to install an `i386` package on an `amd64` system. And the package wasn't designed to be installable on `amd64`.

I suggest trying to convert one of the 64-bit RPMS to a deb with `alien`.